# Compare Nested List With Different Index Amount and Same Condition in Particular List

Tags: python, arraylist, list-comprehension, nested-lists

i have two nested list and the result

```
data1 = [
    ["tr1", 1002, 6798381], # return false
    ["tr1", 1001, 6798381], # return false
    ["tr1", 1001, 6798381], # return false
    ["tr1", 1000, 6798381], # return vid1
    ["tr1", 1000, 6798381], # return vid2 (can be vid1, but vid1 already used) | But I got False
    ["tr2", 1200, 6798382], # vid3
    ["tr4", 1200, 6798384], # vid5
    ["tr5", 1200, 6798385], # false
    ["tr3", 1200, 6798383], # vid4
]

data2 = [
    ["tr1", 1000, 6798381, "vid1"],
    ["tr1", 1000, 6798381, "vid2"],
    ["tr2", 1200, 6798382, "vid3"],
    ["tr3", 1200, 6798383, "vid4"],
    ["tr4", 1200, 6798384, "vid5"]
]
```

i need to move data2 last index(data2[-1] which is vid1 or vid2 etc.) into data1 if value is same, but if data2 vid already taken, i should delete so i dont get multiple data from data2

Code I use

```
for x in data1:
    key = (x[0], x[1], x[2])
    if key in data2_dict:
        print(data2_dict[key])
        # Remove the key from data2_dict to prevent reuse
        del data2_dict[key]
    else:
        print("false")
```

output i get from my code

```
    false
    false
    false
    vid1
    False (should be vid1 or vid2, but vid1 already used so should be vid2)
    vid3
    vid5
    false
    vid4
```

output i expect

```
    false
    false
    false
    vid1
    vid2
    vid3
    vid5
    false
    vid4

or

false
    false
    false
    vid2 --
    vid1 --
    vid3
    vid5
    false
    vid4
```

Edit Expect result :
instead of print vid/false can you move into data1 ?

```
["tr1", 1002, 6798381], # return false
    ["tr1", 1001, 6798381, 'false'], # return false
    ["tr1", 1001, 6798381, 'false'], # return false
    ["tr1", 1000, 6798381, 'vid1'], # return vid1
    ["tr1", 1000, 6798381, 'vid2'], # return vid2 (can be vid1, but vid1 already used) | But I got False
    ["tr2", 1200, 6798382, 'vid3'], # vid3
    ["tr4", 1200, 6798384, 'vid5'], # vid5
    ["tr5", 1200, 6798385, 'false'], # false
    ["tr3", 1200, 6798383, 'vid4'], # vid4
```

can you guys help me? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `vid1` and `vid2` share the same key, it's best to build a dict of lists to keep track of vids of the same keys. When iterating keys from `data1`, pop the vids from the sub-lists of the current keys to prevent reuse. Output `'false'` if `KeyError` is raised from a non-existent key or if `IndexError` is raised from an exhausted sub-list:

```
data = {}
for *key, vid in data2:
    data.setdefault(tuple(key), []).append(vid)
output = []
for key in map(tuple, data1):
    try:
        vid = data[key].pop()
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        vid = 'false'
    output.append([*key, vid])
```

`output` becomes:

```
[['tr1', 1002, 6798381, 'false'],
 ['tr1', 1001, 6798381, 'false'],
 ['tr1', 1001, 6798381, 'false'],
 ['tr1', 1000, 6798381, 'vid2'],
 ['tr1', 1000, 6798381, 'vid1'],
 ['tr2', 1200, 6798382, 'vid3'],
 ['tr4', 1200, 6798384, 'vid5'],
 ['tr5', 1200, 6798385, 'false'],
 ['tr3', 1200, 6798383, 'vid4']]
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZPLTsMwEEX3@YpRWDRGVlXnAQWpGySQKj4h8sJtHIhIbct1UCPg24Njkz7SSrDBq4nnzJ25HkW15lWKZK5015VabkApXQkD1UZJbX6@gqBghhFYQB6APXloNAkxkNksxnBzezdP5oRiuALNTaMFlKze8jFK/gWdXUTfq4L8mYwhWjMBK@7KMKwa4yJgteasaKHZ8gLBJzzYxBJepIGnk1HivkF8aBC7BlYi2SPpCEkHJNsj2QjJHHJqOhkxySCTBtRvKb60pYN1DGFvLaT4NyY@Zs4ceiY5Zs5m80x6zJw9g2eykA7z2/E/voJSarh@4y3uvUElwFm7dzp9ON1yU/CSNbWJTKNqHlkYYcgpmjKluCgiW4gC2Rhll2afhDpNS/VqG6Z8GXZqBHllo1sf9KdvvHDp3FbRqZIqQi7Ld2uuDETPvH3UWmoMS1HwnYvRWGDiFjhxt36aYcB8b5CiwP9okSdQ130D)